# external library binary and entitltments 0, while exporting to ipa xcode 6.1.1

Tags: ios, xcode, external-accessory

I am trying to create an app store distribution provisioned build to submit on apple itunes test flight. I have previously prereleased it many times, but this time i have included external library in my project.
i have cross check my app id services, provisioning profile services, capabilities.

I am attaching screen shot:

[image]

i am not understanding why this external library [external library](https://github.com/iZettle/sdk-ios) present in above summary pane with iZettleSDK(0 entitlements) and "none" provisioning profile.

the issue does not happen when i remove this external library from project, copy bundle resources.

How do i export to iPA  file.

Comment: Strangely, after a year of this question, I have got the same issue. Anyone got a solution to this?